# is there way to put condition on an actionForward in struts config xml file

Tags: java, struts, struts-config

I'm newbie, so please forgive bad terminology, etc...
I want to only follow through on my forward when a condition is met, but I don't know how to incorporate that into my struts config xml. For example, I have this:

```
<action path="somePath"
        type="myTypeClass" 
        parameter="method" 
        scope="request">
    <forward name="myForwardName1" path="myPage1.jsp"/>
    <forward name="myForwardName2" path="myPage2.jsp"/>
</action>
```

But I want this action to only work when a condition is true and throw an exception otherwise. Is there some syntax I can use to this. For example, I want none of the jsp pages to display if my condition is not met, but display some generic error message instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, I don't think it's possible. Your Struts `Action` is where your business logic is implemented and decisions are made there to which `ActionForward` you want Struts to forward to.

Well, there are Struts-Validation that you can look at if you have predefined rules to link to a forward.